# Javascript - Show a pop-up window onChange

Tags: javascript

I want to show a html pop-up window, onChange from an input text to another.

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean a real new window, or a tooltip? And what do you mean by "from one input text to another" - do you mean the `blur` event?

Comment: Or do you mean a [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)? (+1 @Pekka)

Comment: @Bizboss: I'm confused. First you said you wanted to open a new window (e.g. with `window.open()`) but now it sounds like you want a modal dialog. Which is it?

Comment: @Matt Ball: Sorry, I want just to open a php file in a new window

Comment: Extremely annoying when the target moves while answering. Just wasted my time giving a div.

Comment: @mplungjan: I agree that it's annoying, but it's not unusual for that to happen.

Comment: @Bizboss can you please give more details. What EXACTLY do you want to show in the php - a result from the input field? A ajax field suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) solution:

#### HTML

```
<form ...>
   <input type="text" id="first"/>
   <input type="text" id="second"/>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#first').blur(function ()
    {
        alert('show the popup here');
    });
});
```

**[Basic demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ksCng/1/)**.

**[`window.open()` demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Xee45/)**. Disclaimer: this behavior is *extremely* annoying to users.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to open a html file in pop-up and not an alert.

Comment: @Bizboss: then use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.open).

Comment: @Bizboss automatic, programmatical pop-ups are extremely likely to be swallowed by any self-respecting pop-up blocker. I would not go that way

Comment: @Pekka: Chrome's pop-up blocker does not break this.

Comment: @Matt: `Firefox prevented this site from opening a window`

Comment: @Pekka: What is the best solution (for a Magento website). Thanks

Comment: @Bizboss: [modal dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) are common alternatives.

Comment: @Bizboss if Magento is based on jQuery (I don't remember right now), jQuery UI's dialogs are the way to go as shown in @Matt's link

Comment: It seems to be mootools based

Comment: Magento is based on Prototype, but I think that it is possible to use also jQuery on it (but I don't know how...)